# Get the id of the second element

Tags: jquery

I have a table structure like this

```
<tr>
<td>Cover Banner</td>
<td><div id="coverPreview"></div></td>
<td><input type='file' id="coverBanner"/></td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is when I click on file browse button, I have to get the previous id i.e "coverPreview"

I did like this

```
$(this).closest('tr').children(':first-child').next().attr("id")
```

The result I am getting is undefined. Could anyone help me.

Comment: `$(this).parent().prev().find('div').attr("id")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try getting the `closest('td')` and using `prev()` and `find()` from there. Try this:

```
var divId = $(this).closest('td').prev().find('div').prop('id');
```

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  var divId = $(this).closest('td').prev().find('div').prop('id');
  console.log(divId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cover Banner</td>
    <td>
      <div id="coverPreview"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="file" id="coverBanner" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have one div in tr so you can search for it using `find()` inside parent element.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('div').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 $(this).parent().prev().children().attr("id");
```

Read more about [jQuery Traversing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#coverBanner').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().prev().find('div').attr("id"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cover Banner</td>
    <td>
      <div id="coverPreview"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='file' id="coverBanner" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use `.parent()` , `.prev()` and `.find()`

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way

```
$("this").parent().siblings().find("div").attr("id");

or

$("this").parent().prev().find("div").attr("id");
```